# QGIS. Fill nodata using a vector data and mask?

Tags: qgis

How to fill the missing Grid.asc data up to a vector line so that the height value on the line with interpolation = 0m? The 'Fill nodata' tool fills the data to the line but continues values >0 and the mask is raster only.

[image]